# Exporting from blender to Marvelous designer?

Tags: animation, export

I have a character with an animated armature. 
I want to export it to marvelous designer5, with animation.
What would be the right process? 
[image: My model]

Comment: Try the autodesk FBX exporter. ;3

Comment: What formats can be imported into Marvelous Designer 5?

Comment: @Samoth - MD5 can take animated OBJ and FBX.

Comment: @Tavuk - you mean export FBX from blender than use the autodesk exporter? Or is a blender addon? And does it require baking the animation before exporting?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I exported Collada and MDD (needed to turn on MDD export in addon manager). Imported them to Marvelous designer and animated, than exported the same to Blender - Collada and MDD.